# Reducing Branching in Generic Tree Traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

So I'm not completely sure if this question belongs here or on Software Engineering, but since I'm specifically interested in the C++ implementation, I'm asking here.

Now, with that out of the way, I've implemented a basic binary tree with a generic traversal function meant to handle pre-order, in-order, and post-order all in one.

```
void BiTree::_trav(BiNode* root, int offset, function<void (int&,int&)> lambda) {

    if (root == NULL) {return;}
    auto call = [&] () {lambda(root->data, root->sc);};

    if (offset == 0) { call();}

    _trav(root->child[0], offset, lambda);

    if (offset == 1) { call();}

    _trav(root->child[1], offset, lambda);

    if (offset == 2) { call();}
}
```

As you can see, this function calls itself recursively, and has a lot of branches. As not everyone knows C++ or about lambdas in C++ (I didn't yesterday), here is the same idea reduced down to the problem.

```
void BiTree::_trav(BiNode* root, int offset) {

    if (root == NULL) {return;}

    if (offset == 0) { do_thing();}

    _trav(root->child[0], offset, lambda);

    if (offset == 1) { do_thing();}

    _trav(root->child[1], offset, lambda);

    if (offset == 2) { do_thing();}
}
```

My programming intuition says that there is a better way to do this, with less branching, but I can't figure out how. A switch statement wouldn't work because then `do-thing()` is called more than once, or has even more branches. So I'm interested in how to do a generic tree traversal with minimal branching.

Comment: All-in-one and maximum performance tend to be contradictory goals.  Given that each function is only 5 lines of code, maximum performance is achieved by writing the three separate functions: pre-order, in-order, and post-order. Not only does it eliminate the branching, but it also eliminates the need to pass `offset` at each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question using an array of dummy functions and inserting the function with the code I actually want to run where I want to run it. I'm not sure if this improves performance, but it seems to have reduced branching.

```
void BiTree::_trav(BiNode* root, int offset, function<void (int&,int&)> lambda) {
    if (root == NULL) {return;}

    function<void (void)> branches[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        branches[i] = [&] () {};
    }
    function<void (void)> call  = [&] () {lambda(root->data, root->sc);};
    branches[offset] = call;

    branches[0]();

    _trav(root->child[0], offset, lambda);

    branches[1]();

    _trav(root->child[1], offset, lambda);

    branches[2]();
}
```